# Can you combine loyalty programs when flying on a multi itinerary flight?

Tags: loyalty-programs, star-alliance, skyteam

I fly mostly with SAS, and thus I earn points on their EuroBonus loyalty programs. I am soon travelling from Europe to Japan with KLM, and will use their FlyingBlue program, since EuroBonus cannot be used.

However, I noticed that part of the journey is flown by Air Nippon, who are Star Alliance members, just like SAS. Is it possible to somehow earn EuroBonus points on this part of the trip? Or will I earn FlyingBlue points regardless?

If possible, how would one go about doing that? Should I sign up for ANA's loyalty program, and then attempt to transfer the points? ([This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/25291/3956) suggests points can not be transferred). Does it matter that I did not order and pay for the tickets personally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your flight on ANA has a flight number that begins with "NH", then you can submit that flight to SAS's EuroBonus for consideration.  But how many points you earn will depend on the fare class that was booked.  Many times the cheaper fare classes get only a small percentage of what SAS would award (sometimes no points).  The SAS website has a brief breakdown of minimum points awarded, but not a detailed explanation  [www.flysas.com/en/us/eurobonus/earn-points/airlines/](http://www.flysas.com/en/us/eurobonus/earn-points/airlines/).

If the flight is a codeshare and the flight number begins with a "KL", then the points will be credited towards your FlyingBlue account.  If you haven't signed up yet for FlyingBlue, please know that KLM, Air France and Delta all award points equally, so you could choose any of those programs and have your KLM flight credited (depending on which you might fly the most in the future).

Answer (score 9):

Generally if you flew with an airline, and you have points with them or their alliance, whoever you hold the points with, you can credit.

So I had an itinerary last year that involved some major US Airline (Delta?) and then Alaska Airlines.  It's possible to credit Alaska Airlines to One World alliance airlines, and I'm with Qantas.

So when I'd done the flight, I rang up Qantas, gave them my flight number, seat, date, and details and they credited me points for flying on their 'partner' airline.

Of course, this isn't always the case - and it pays to check the smallprint.  If you have a Qantas/Jetstar flight, depending on the class of your Jetstar ticket, you aren't always able to claim - well, you can claim for Qantas points, but it'll just show up as '0 points'.  Which happens regularly for me when I fly to NZ from Australia :/

Comment: Yes – but there's an added hurdle here, because SAS and KLM are in different alliances, but KLM has interlined (?) part of the journey to ANA (who does share alliance with SAS). The trip as a whole is ordered through KLM directly. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Nix It seems to be similar to Mark's Delta (SkyTeam)/Alaska Airlines (One World)/Qantas (One World) situation.

Comment: @Relaxed Ah, I see, that does look similar. In that case, this might be as close as we get to a generally correct answer.